# How to create a new project in adobe-brackets?

Tags: editor, html-editor, adobe-brackets

I've started using [adobe-brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) for editing JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

Currently I have the "Getting Started" project open in my side bar. I would like to **create a new project**, but there is no such "New Project" item in the File menu.

I tried clicking on "Project settings", but that just gives me this:

[image: Getting Started project settings]

How do you get rid of the default "Getting Started" project, and start a fresh new one?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's suppose you want your project to be in this location:

```
/Users/myName/Sites/mySite
```

To create a new project here you need just to do this:

1. File -> Open Folder -> /Users/myName/Sites/mySite

Congrats, you've just created a new project! You will see the new project displayed on the top of the left menu.

Answer (score 6):

You have to install Brackets new project creator.