# How to open an sshfs-project in Adobe Brackets editor

Tags: sshfs, adobe-brackets

adobe-brackets is an open source code editor for the web, written in JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

Although I followed the instructions on how to open a Project ( see also [How to create a new project in adobe-brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937018/how-to-create-a-project-in-adobe-brackets-editor)) this does not work for my project-directory which is mapped via sshfs.

Brackets will show the sshfs directory but without any contents. (neither files nor subdirs)
Opening other locally stored directories works like a charm.

Any hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*Update:* This is [fixed](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/pull/369) in the [latest release of Brackets](http://download.brackets.io), Sprint 34. You should now be able to open files on SSHFS file systems with no trouble.

---

*original answer:*

> What platform are you on? If Linux, you might be seeing [bug #5292](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5292), which is currently under investigation.
>
> If not, it might be best if you just [file a new bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/new) specifying your platform and any other details, and then the Brackets devs (of which I am one) can take a look. When reporting a bug, always check the console log via *Debug > Show Developer Tools* and paste any exceptions there into your bug report.